# Cómo cambio el html a partir de javascript, de modo que este html tenga un id y pueda manipularlo en el futuro ocn js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Éste es mi código:

```
<div class="meal">
    <p id="lunAlm" class="food"></p>
    <span id="lunAlmI">
        <input type="text" id="lunAlmV">
        <button id="lunAlmB">go!</button>
    </span>
    <p id="lunAlmC">+Ensalada</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var almLun = "";

$("#lunAlmB").click(function () {

    //var feed="";
    almLun = $("#lunAlmV").val();

    $("#lunAlm").html(almLun);
    $("#lunAlmI").html("");

    $("#lunAlmC").click(function () {

        $("#lunAlmI").html(
            '<input type="text" id="lunAlmV"><button id="lunAlmB">go!</button>'
        );
        $("#lunAlm").html("");

    });
});
```

Mi intención es que la primera función cambie el html, y la segunda me dé la posibilidad de volver al htmloriginal. El problema que tengo es que al volver intentar ejecutar la primera función esta no se ejecuta, no funciona el onclick.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso te pasa por que luego de cambiar el html añades de manera dinámica nuevamente el html anterior por lo cual el botón ya no es reconocido al seleccionarlo directamente, para solucionar esto debes cambiar tu selector y seleccionar primero el documento, de la siguiente manera:

```js
var almLun="";

$(document).on('click', '#lunAlmB', function(){
  //var feed="";
  almLun= $("#lunAlmV").val();

  $("#lunAlm").html(almLun);
  $("#lunAlmI").html("");
});

$("#lunAlmC").click(function(){
  $("#lunAlmI").html('<input type="text" id="lunAlmV"><button id="lunAlmB">go!</button>');
  $("#lunAlm").html("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="meal"><p id="lunAlm" class="food"></p><span id="lunAlmI"><input type="text" id="lunAlmV"><button id="lunAlmB">go!</button></span><p id="lunAlmC">+Ensalada</p></div>
```

Comment: Ni bien pueda lo pruebo. Muchas gracias!